# Android: draw9path doesn't not work on Emulator

Tags: android, android-layout, nine-patch

I 'm using Android draw9path for an image that I will set for background.

after I process picture on software (default tools of `android SDK`) an put it in drawable-hdpi folder, and put it in background by:

`android:background="@drawable/background"`.

I test successfully on `graphical view`, but when I run on Emulator, `Android Emulator` acts as normal image.

Who can help me solve this issue, please.

thanks :)

Comment: if you uploaded the image it will be useful to find the issue. BTW is that saved with .9 extension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you didn't create p pitch image properly.

save the file like filename.9.png